# Retrieving value from useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a problem regarding my current function `checkResultOfCards`. This function is unable to retrieve a updated value (`currentAnswer`) from a `useState`-Hook which I update through a TextInput. My codesample may be long but consider that half of it are `useEffect`-hooks which render only once under a special condition. That said, here is my code so far:

```
const PracticeScreen = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const myLibrary = useSelector(state => state.myLibrary.myLibrary);
  const myBottomTab = useSelector(state => state.myOtherReducers.showBottomTab);

  const backActionRef = useRef(null);
  const swiperRef = useRef(null);

  const [loadedCardStack, setLoadedCardStack] = useState([]);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [currentAnswer, setCurrentAnswer] = useState("");

  const [wrongCards, setWrongCards] = useState([]);
  const [goodCards, setGoodCards] = useState([]);
  const [isAnswerRight, setIsAnswerRight] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    /**listener sub and unsub when changing screen
     * dispatching of bottom tab nav happening here*/
    const backAction = () => {
      Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to exit the course?", [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => null,
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "YES", onPress: () => {
          dispatch(SpecialActions.setBottomTabVisibility("flex"));
          props.navigation.goBack()
        }}
      ],{cancelable: false});
      return true;
    };

    backActionRef.current = backAction;

    const backHandler = () => {
      backActionRef.current();
      return true;
    };

    // event listener when the screen comes into focus
    const focusListener = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backHandler);
    });

    // removing of the listener when the screen goes out of focus
    const blurListener = props.navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      dispatch(SpecialActions.setBottomTabVisibility("flex"));
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backHandler);
    });

    return () => {
      focusListener();
      blurListener();
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backHandler);
    }
  }, [props.navigation]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    /*Layoutstyling for header must be here, not in Navigator.js*/
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: 'Practice Screen',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#7dbae5',
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        borderBottomColor: 'black',
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: 'black',
      },
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to exit the course?", [
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              onPress: () => null,
              style: "cancel"
            },
            { text: "YES", onPress: () => {
              dispatch(SpecialActions.setBottomTabVisibility("flex"));
              props.navigation.goBack()}}
          ],{cancelable: false});
        }}>
          <AntDesign name="caretleft" size={24} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
        }}>
          <AntDesign name="infocirlce" size={24} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    });
  }, [props.navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    /*loading up the Cards */ 
    loadCardStack();
  }, []);


  const loadCardStack = () => {
    setLoadedCardStack(props.route.params.courseData.cards);
    console.log("here is your stack :",loadedCardStack)
  };
  console.log("RERENDER")//checking if after each typing into TextInput this log triggers, and yes it does and so must the useState be updated
  const checkResultOfCard = (rightAnswer) => {
    //if wrong question, mark card, else add to positive stack
    if(currentAnswer !== rightAnswer){
      setIsAnswerRight(false);
      console.log("wrong answer: ", currentAnswer, "also the type: ", typeof(currentAnswer))
    }else{
      setIsAnswerRight(true);
      console.log("good answer")
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView 
        style={styles.container} 
        behavior='height' 
        keyboardVerticalOffset={-(Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.18)} 
        enabled
      >
        {loadedCardStack.length > 0 && (
        <CardStack 
          style={styles.CardStackStyle} 
          ref={swiperRef}
          loop={true}
          verticalSwipe={false}
        >
          {loadedCardStack.map((card, index) => (
            <Card key={card.q1} style={styles.cardStyle1}>
              <View style={styles.splitCard}>
                <Text style={styles.question1}>{card.q1}</Text>
                <TextInput 
                  style={styles.textEdit1}
                  placeholder=" answer"
                  onChangeText={text => {
                    setCurrentAnswer(text)//THIS IS WHERE I CHANGE THE STATE
                  }}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.buttonStyle}
                  onPress={() => {
                    checkResultOfCard(card.answer); //HERE I CALL THE FUNCION WHICH FAILS ITS TASK
                  }}
                >
                <Text>Check Result</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.splitCard}>
               
              </View>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </CardStack>
        )}
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

It probably has something to do with the State beeing updated but the function not recognizing the new value of the Hook. I tried to write the code from scratch and try out a demo on my own, here is a short example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const myfunction = () =>{
    alert(text)
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => setText(text)//HERE I CHANGE THE STATE}
      />
      <Button
        title="Retrieve Text"
        onPress={() => {
          myfunction();//HERE I CALL THE FUNCTION, IT WORKS
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

It is the same logic with also a pressable object firing a function but in this case everything works perfectly! Thats why I am confuced and reaching out for your help and some tips how I can fix my code to make it work like in the demo, the second example.

EDIT: [This is the Card-Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-card-stack-swiper) I am using for the `<CardStack>` and `<Card>` elements. Also it is **mandatory** that I somehow make the `useState`-hooks working. I plan to add features like changing color of the `<Card>` and this wont be possible without rerendering, which should be triggered by an change in a State.

Comment: try using useCallback on checkResultOfCard

Comment: I tested your code it was working fine, this the sample your code on snack https://snack.expo.dev/jtuzqwKdC2, did you have some popup or alert running after the input? this popup can reset the usestate data.

Comment: @AndreBahtiarFauzi I already tried to apply `useCallback` to my function, my idea was to rerender the function when the `currentAnswer` changes but this didnt help at all, same behavior.

Comment: @suryadi I have a `modal` which is directly after the `<CardStack>` but this has its own `useState` and it has neither any shared variables with my function nor I use it while debugging this problem here.

Comment: CardStack and Card not included on the code so I use view, and cannot recreate the issue, include the code

Comment: @suryadi Im sorry I didnt include it earlier, it is a package I will add to the end of my post. 

I did not include it because, as you did, I also exchanged it with a `View` to see if this maybe fixes the issue but I got the same results

Comment: Although it's inefficient, the code should be working unless there are two cards with the same `q1` property in the loop (`card.q1`).

Comment: Try the following `setCurrentAnswer(() => text)` (Pass a function to setState)

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code to recreate the error and it seems to work. See the code sample below:

```
function App() {
  const loadedCardStack = [
    {
      q1: "What is your name?",
      answer: "john"
    }
  ];

  const [currentAnswer, setCurrentAnswer] = useState("");

  const [isAnswerRight, setIsAnswerRight] = useState(null);

  const checkResultOfCard = (rightAnswer) => {
    //if wrong question, mark card, else add to positive stack
    setIsAnswerRight(
      rightAnswer &&
        currentAnswer.trim().toLowerCase() === rightAnswer.trim().toLowerCase()
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      {loadedCardStack.map((card, index) => (
        <View>
          <Text>{card.q1}</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{ borderColor: "#ddd", borderWidth: 1, margin: 10 }}
            placeholder="answer"
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setCurrentAnswer(text); //THIS IS WHERE I CHANGE THE STATE
            }}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              checkResultOfCard(card.answer); //HERE I CALL THE FUNCION WHICH FAILS ITS TASK
            }}
            style={{ marginTop: 7, backgroundColor: "orange" }}
          >
            <Text>Check Result</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ))}
      <Text>Answer: {isAnswerRight ? "Correct" : "Incorrect"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can see it live here: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-sea-xn5ikq?file=/src/App.js:146-1373

I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. I barely made any changes except for the `checkResultOfCard` function.

Note that for your code, you have to type the answer in the correct case. i.e.: If the answer is `John` and you type `john` it will be marked as incorrect. So I changed the function to convert the string to lowercase before comparing. Also, I trimmed the white spaces from both ends.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your code works indeed, the major reason it does is because you dont use the `<Card>` module :) I dont know how to describe this behavior but it seems to me that the Card-components save a snapshot of all states at the beginning and refuse to update it. Changing out `<Card>` with `<View>` solves the problem with the `useState` not beeing updated already even though it destroys the UI completely but thats not important for now. 

You probably can not try this module out in the sandbox in the browser but I linked the package in the post at the end incase you want to play with it offline.

Comment: That said, your solution helped me but probably in a totaly different way then both of us expected :)

Comment: Can you try something like this: https://snack.expo.dev/@maheshsamudra/react-native-cards

Comment: "I barely made any changes except for the checkResultOfCard function." -- I replaced your `checkResultOfCard` with the one in OP and it still worked.

Comment: [TKol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959054/tkol) In the OP, it won't work if the answer is "John" and you type "john"

Answer (score 0):

you need to use array for this case.

```
// put this on global
let arrayAnswer = Array();

// change checkResultOfCard  function
const checkResultOfCard = (rightAnswer, index) => {
    //if wrong question, mark card, else add to positive stack
    if (arrayAnswer[index] !== rightAnswer) {
      setIsAnswerRight(false);
      
      console.log('array : ', arrayAnswer[index]);
      
    } else {
      setIsAnswerRight(true);
      console.log('good answer');
    }
};

//and lastly put the set on array on textinput
<TextInput
  style={styles.textEdit1}
  placeholder=" answer"
  onChangeText={(text) => {
    let data;
    arrayAnswer[index] = text;
    console.log('arrayAnswer',arrayAnswer, index)
    
    setCurrentAnswer(text); //THIS IS WHERE I CHANGE THE STATE
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Even though technicaly this is working, it totaly nullifies the sense of the `useState` hooks which are a core part of react-native. My code depends on them and will depend in future when I expand it because changing the state invokes a rerender of the components, at least it should do that. In my post it does not and that is my problem. I dont want to sound mean but its like my car would be broken and you brought me a bicycle with an engine taped to the side :) I am able to drive it but its insecure and lacks features I depend on.

Comment: If the question only 1, then useState will work without any issue, but if more than 1 question usestate will not be able to handle it, in your app did you not saving all the answer for summary? my answer still using simple array, or array on usestate

Answer (score 0):

Attached my code on snack.
https://snack.expo.dev/@jonasbeck.dev/retrieving-value-from-usestate-hook
I guess the reason of issue would be Card component refer state value as constant with initial value.
Let me try to explain with a similar case.

With the example code below, the value of 't' is always 1 not increazing value per 1 sec because 't' is referred to constant 0 inside the parameter function of 'setInterval'.

> ```
> const [t, setT] = useState(0)
> setInterval(()=>{
>  setT(t+1)
> }, 1000)
> ```

The solution is to use setState callback like this:

> ```
> const [t, setT] = useState(0)
> setInterval(()=>{
>  setT(prevState=>prevState+1)
> }, 1000)
> ```

like that I can fix your code.

> ```
>   const checkResultOfCard = (rightAnswer) => {
>     //if wrong question, mark card, else add to positive stack
>     setRightAnswer(prevState=>{
>      setIsAnswerRight(
>        rightAnswer &&
>          currentAnswer.trim().toLowerCase() === rightAnswer.trim().toLowerCase()
>      );
>      return prevState;
>     });
>   };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In general it's a bad practise to directly update state from an input. Create a handle function with a debounce for the text input state update.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: https://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-stack-swiper/blob/master/CardStack.js#L154

When the top component re-renders (due to the `setCurrentAnswer` call), the CardStack re-renders and its `componentDidUpdate` is called (because its `children` prop effectively changed).

But it then determines that the children are the same (because the array length is the same and all the childs' `key` remain the same and in the same order). So it skips updating its state (namely the `cardA` and `cardB` properties).

And those are the properties used at the `render` method, instead of directly the `children` property (https://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-stack-swiper/blob/master/CardStack.js#L404).

It will render the old set of childs instead of the new one, so the `TouchableOpacity` is one with an old reference of `checkResultOfCard` in its closure. Notice it is not a problem for the input (the inputted text doesn't get replaced) because it is a native html element, uncontrolled by design.

This basically is a poor implementation by react-native-card-stack-swiper. You should open a bug or submit a fix. Meanwhile, as a workaround, you may try to force the full re-render by changing the card key (`key={card.q1 + A_COUNTER_OR_SOMETHING_ELSE}`). Or change the implementation of `checkResultOfCard` for fetching the answer value directly from the input (using a ref).